# Is "that"a conjunction or other grammatical function in the emphatic structure"It is .... that ..."?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, sentence-patterns, emphasis

For example, in the following sentence

> It is Mary **that** brought me this book.

Does "that" serve as a conjunction or pronoun or any other grammatical function? And Why?

Comment: It’s a subordinator, what traditional grammar used to call a subordinating conjunction.

Comment: Yes, its job is solely to introduce the relative clause "that brought me this book". Traditionally analysed as a relative pronoun, but more correctly as a subordinator, the same as the "that" which introduces declarative content clauses.

Comment: This is the construction often called an _It_-Cleft, or just a Cleft sentence. It's generated by rule from _Mary brought me this book_ by cleaving the sentence with an auxiliary _be_ and inserting a dummy _it_ and a complementizer (or relative pronoun) _that_ for the postposed clause. There are also _Wh_-Clefts, like _What Mary brought me was this book._, [as well as other varieties](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf).

Comment: Yes, a cleft, but the question is specifically about the word "that". It cannot be a complementizer because the relative clause it introduces is not a complement but a postnucleus. And the claim that it's a relative pronoun has long been proved wrong. So **subordinator** is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand on BillJ and Araucaria's comments, though I'm not claiming they endorse any of what follows.

It’s part of the tiny subordinator class made up of *whether, if, for, that* and *to*, what traditional grammar used to call a subordinating conjunction: a relatively meaningless left-end marker required by syntax in certain constructions and optional in others. Its job is solely to introduce the relative clause *that brought me this book*.

The claim that it's a relative pronoun has long been proven wrong: it is the same marker of clause subordination as we find in content clauses, and the distinction between *that* and bare relatives is analogous to that between expanded and bare declarative content clauses, as in *You said (that) you don’t want the toys*.

1. It can't be the object of a preposition, which it should be able to
   were it a pronoun.

> It was this knife [with which he cut it].
>
> *It was this knife [with that he cut it].

2. It can appear in a wide range of relatives which would require a particular *wh* word and even in some where no *wh* word is possible. Inserting the *wh* relative pronouns (or proforms) into the gap produces grammatical results whereas *that* often does not - or results in a meaning that could not possibly be the equivalent of the relative clause. This is because it is simply a left-end marker of subordination in these constructions - a subordinator and not a proform.

> They gave the prize to the **girl** [that/who spoke first].
>
> Who spoke first?
>
> That spoke first?

> Have you seen the **book** [that/which she was reading]?
>
> She was reading which?
>
> She was reading that?

> It was that **day** [that/when she arrived].
>
> She arrived when?
>
> *She arrived that?

> It was **to this town** [that/- she went].
>
> *She went that?

> It was **for this reason** [that/- she resigned].
>
> She resigned that?

> It was this **way** [that/- she controlled the crowd].
>
> *She controlled the crowd that.

> It wasn’t **to** **you** [that/- I was referring].
>
> *I was referring that.

It also cannot be a complementizer because the element it introduces is not a complement.

> **complementizer** A word that introduces a clause [...] which functions
> as complement to a verb or some other head. The items ***that***, ***whether***,
> ***if*** (in interrogative clauses), and ***for*** belong to this class.[...]It is
> narrower in meaning than subordinating conjunction or subordinator.
> (The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar)

Since there is no head that it is specifically allowed by, it is clearly outside this definition.

So subordinator (or if you prefer traditional terminology subordinating conjunction) is the answer to your question.

Comment: +1 For *CaGEL*, there’s also ‘declarative’ *how* in that small group. Re ‘complement’ isn’t the RC a complement of the verb *be* there?

Answer (score 0):

John Lawler commented:

> This is the construction often called an It-Cleft, or just a Cleft sentence. It's generated by rule from *Mary brought me this book* by cleaving the sentence with an auxiliary *be* and inserting a dummy *it* and a complementizer (or relative pronoun) *that* for the postposed clause. There are also Wh-Clefts, like *What Mary brought me was this book,* [as well as other varieties.](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Nobbut.pdf)